# Downgrade glibc on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, glibc

Ubuntu 18.04 comes with glibc 2.27. This breaks some tools I'm currently using for a project. Is there any way for me to downgrade glibc in 18.04 to 2.26? apt-cache shows that only version 2.27 is available in the repo.

Comment: similar to: https://superuser.com/questions/557395/how-to-revert-to-older-version-of-libc6-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you question is quite connected (or even duplicate with) [/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65120136/lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-18-not-found)

Anyway...

It is not a good idea at all try to downgrade the libc version of you linux distribution.

It might would work if you compile it by yourself but I'm quite sure the whole system will be broken after replace it. All the Libs and Tools which are coming with your distribution are most probably linked against 2.27 and if you downgrade those requirements won't be matched anymore.

The version of libc is defining you distribution like the version of the kernel (or even more).

Comment: Thanks for yor Answers..so their any way to have 2 glibc version on same host and compile graal native image with different version?

Comment: directly on the system could be quite hard.. what you can do: build your image in a docker-container which is matching the target system.. a container brings it's on version of the Libc